# Is my model overfitting? Values seem too good to be true

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm using this code to generate test and train datasets, fit a classifier to it, and return several metrics. However, I've been getting extremely good scores. Am I overfitting, or just being oversuspicious?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
'''
@author: nelson-liu
'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


alldata = pd.read_csv('alldata60.csv')

cols = [col for col in alldata.columns if col not in ['Survival months', 'Survived']]

X = alldata[cols].values
y = alldata["Survived"].values

Xr, Xt, yr, yt = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=6131997)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2000, oob_score=True)
rfc.fit(Xr, yr)
ypred = rfc.predict(Xt)
acc = rfc.score(Xt, yt)
scores = cross_val_score(rfc, Xr, yr, cv=10)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()*2))
print mean_squared_error(yt, ypred)
print rfc.oob_score_
print accuracy_score(yt,ypred)
print acc
```

The values that were returned were:

```
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.00)
0.0245367883996 (MSE)
0.975742385929 (oob_score)
0.9754632116 (accuracy score)
0.9754632116 (random forest classifier class' score)
```

I took care to ensure that i used a held-out test set, which would ensure that i saw terrible results if i was indeed overfitting. However, the results seem good nonetheless. Being an ML newbie, I'd definitely appreciate a 2nd pair of eyes taking a look.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using same dataset for training and testing purpose?

Comment: Rather than just doing a straight split you could do a [k-fold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) and then look at the performance for each split, if it performs well against all then it should be a good indication of generalised performance. You may even get a lower average performance which is fine so long as your trained model does not overfit, the rest of the page that I linked to has a good description and explanation of how to combat this

Comment: @user123 the training and testing data comes from the same dataset, but it was split with train_test_split().
Edchum: I will look into it, and post my results.

Comment: Perhaps your classification problem is just easy. Hard to tell without knowing how do your data look like.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm using the SEER cancer database to classify patients of breast cancer as either survived (lived for 60+ months after diagnosis) or did not survive (died due to cancer <60 months after diagnosis). It's an easy problem, but I am surprised to get such good results, as the highest result I've seen in literature is around 87%

Comment: If are learned with some dataset and if you use similar for testing then it will always give you such accurate result. Because it has already learned and knowing it. Try test with substituting some different queries

Comment: (1/2) @user123, im not quite sure if i'm understanding what you're saying. I had one large dataset (we'll call it A). {A} has attributes, as well as the target value I want to predict. I split {A} into two datasets, {X} and {y}. {X} is identically the same as {A}, but with the target column removed. {y} is only the target column. I then split {X} into two datasets, {Xt(est} and {Xr(train)}. 75% of the {X} went into {Xr}, and 25% went to {Xt}. I did the same with {Y}. I trained the classifier on the (train) type datasets, and did not expose them to the tests until after it was done training.

Comment: (2/2) @user123 I then used randomforestclassifier.predict() to predict the values of {yt} given {Xt}. I'm not sure if this constitutes being from the same dataset or not, because while they were from the same dataset, the data used in training is completely different and isolated from the data used in testing. Please let me know if you have any questions / if I got anything wrong.

Comment: @EdChum, i ran:
scores = cross_val_score(rfc, Xr, yr, cv=10)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()*2))

The output i received was "Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.00)"
Is my model overfitting free?

Comment: @NelsonLiu 1) Verify the ratio of labels in the testing set (if it's not ~50/50 you should balance it using some special form of sampling when forming training/test sets). 2) Use k-fold cross-validation, as already suggested by EdChum.

Comment: @NelsonLiu, what features are available in the SEER dataset? From a theoretical standpoint, whether or not you're overfitting is related to the dimensionality of the feature space, and the number of training examples you have. So, if your feature space is very high dimensional, and you're using a (relatively) small number of examples, then you're almost certainly overfitting. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality

Comment: @Nli10Me there are around ~50 features, and I'm currently dealing with 20 features.

Comment: I don't see where you are using KFolds or other n number of splits, are you following the online [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold) correctly? you should be calling `kf = KFold(len(alldata), n_folds=5)` this returns an iterable object and you then iterate over this which provides the indice values to use to access your alldata rows.

Comment: Could you compute the auROC and the auPR too? And give the class balance : if you have 98% of '1' and 2% of '0' and your classifier says always '1' it will have an accuracy of 98% but terrible perfs.

Comment: @AdrienNK the original dataset is perfectly balanced (50% survive and 50% do not survive). However, i use train_test_split to randomly generate training and test sets; by your definition of class balance, I think this method would cause it to be inequitable? Can you suggest any alternatives? Also, what do auROC and auPR mean?

Comment: @EdChum, I used cross_val_score, which is supposedly a wrapper for what you described, but I will implement the method you described and get back to you.

Comment: @NelsonLiu auROC is the Area Under the ROC curve. As you said you were a beginner with ML the ROC and PR curves are two very interesting concepts, you should look them up on wikipedia or so, even if in the end it's not related to your issue it's always good to have that in mind. Basically they are measures of the performances, like the accuracy, that focus on more specific things (and disreagard class imbalance). auROC focus on the classification of positive class (so you can see how your model reacts to positives), auPR is kinda the same idea.

Comment: @NelsonLiu, So you're using 20 out of ~50 available features. How many datapoints are in your training set for each label?

Comment: The ROC curve (Receiver Operating Characteristic, though that name isn't very helpful in learning what the curve is) is basically a plot of the true positive rate over the false positive rate. You want the area under this curve to be as large as possible, that is, the curve gets as close to the upper left corner as possible. That way, you have high true positive, with low false positive. Any good machine learning paper will report ROC curves.

Comment: Check your 10 cross validation scores. do you see big fluctuations in the scores?